# Cant open/explore any folders after win7 to win8 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-8

I just upgraded from **Windows 7 professional (32 bit)** to **Windows 8 pro (32 bit)**. But with the new OS, I can't anymore open folders on my disks by double clicking in explorer window or by right click - select open.

When I try to do so, all open folder windows just close, but all other programs just continue running(probably explorer restarts).

Another problem is that I'm not able to start any program with admin privileges.

What  is causing this & how to solve this ?

## Edit:

Everything works fine in safe mode though.

Comment: As usual with Windows, upgrades can be messy with all kinds of weirdness after upgrading, clean install is always best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by just creating a new User account with admin privileges, remove my old user account that was moved from win 7 to win 8,  using safe mode & finally everything now works fine using the new user account.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a long shot, but it is possible you had some weird folder permissions under Windows 7 which got messed up during the update.

Given your current situation, try taking ownership of a folder or two and see if it lets you into them.

If you aren't familiar with how to do that, read through [this guide](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/take-ownership-of-files-folder-and-change-permissions-in-windows-8/) (there is a few steps to it.)

If taking ownership allows you to get into your folders again, I strongly recommend taking ownership of the folders with your files inside, backing them up and then performing a clean install of Windows 8 to avoid any other weird hiccups down the road.