# In my Windows8, Open or double click(mouse) open does not open folder(explorer.exe crashes & restarts) but "open in new window" works

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

About an year ago, when I migrated from win7 to win8, I asked this question:

> [Cant open/explore any folders after win7 to win8 upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/496125/cant-open-explore-any-folders-after-win7-to-win8-upgrade)

But this has again started to happen, I *can* open any window using

> **Right click > Select "Open in new Window"**

but *cannot* open any folder using mouse double click or doing mouse right click, then select open. The result is explorer.exe seems to crash, explorer.exe then restarts  & all open folder just get closed. I am using Win 8 Pro.

Comment: Your solution isn't working anymore now?

Comment: it does work but I can't create a new user account everytime this occurs.

Comment: create a crash dump and upload the compressed dmp file: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ